# How do I change a key with keydownevent

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change the decimal key on keyboard numpad from a dot to a comma (en-ZA).

Will appreciate some help.

Nothing happen when key.decimal '.' is pressed and no key is inserted

```
private void TimesheetDataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Decimal)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            KeyEventArgs args = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,               
  Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.OemComma);
            args.RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent;
            InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(args);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to programmatically raise the `TextCompositionManager.TextInputEvent` like this:

```
private void TimesheetDataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.OemPeriod)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Keyboard.FocusedElement.RaiseEvent(
          new TextCompositionEventArgs(InputManager.Current.PrimaryKeyboardDevice,
            new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, Keyboard.FocusedElement, ","))
          { RoutedEvent = TextCompositionManager.TextInputEvent }
        );
    }
}
```